# BWToolkit Token Header?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I've had a lot of great help from everyone on here. I've been told I need to remove the Token headers from my BWToolkit framework or it will be rejected (outlined [here](http://bwalkin.lighthouseapp.com/projects/36323-bwtoolkit/tickets/72))

However, being new to Cocoa, i'm not sure how to do this without screwing it up. Can someone explain in dummies terms how I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment earlier, you need to remove the private API offending headers. They are: `NSTokenAttachment.h` and `NSTokenAttachmentCell.h`.

Well, it looks like you want a detailed step by step process.  Here we go. **:)**

---

**First of all, find the `BWToolkitFramework` that you downloaded.**

[image]

**Next, open `Headers`**

[image]

**Delete these two files:**

[image]

And you're done.  Wasn't that hard, was it? :)

Comment: Sudo -

I really appreciate the detailed process. Thank you so much! And no, guess it's not that hard (that was my guess but I didn't want to ruin the framework lol). Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Zakman: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude.  I understand the concern. :)

Comment: No rude-ness taken! I'm genuinely thanking you for putting in the time to do pictures and everything - being new to cocoa, it is very helpful to have that and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

ByteProject has released a new version of the BWtoolkit without any private api.

They removed BWTokenField, which uses NSTokenAttachmentCell and this is private API3

more info here : http://byteproject.net/